# Accessing state set with getDerivedStateFromProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to understand how this new life cycle method (getDerivedStateFromProps) works in react and I'm not sure why I can't access the state field after I set it using this method.
I'll explain what I mean by this.

State:

```
this.state = {
  status: "Activ",
  currPage: "1",
  favorites: [],
  profileType: ""
};
```

Bellow is the method where I compare the nextProps with the prevState and I return the object which sets the state. This works fine and the state is set correctly.

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
  if (nextProps.profile) {
    if (nextProps.profile !== prevState.profileType) {
      return { profileType: nextProps.profile.profile.profileType };
    }
  }

  return null;
}
```

[image]

Next, in componentDidMount() I'm trying to log the profileType from the state. From what I read, this method is called after getDerivedStateFromProps so, the state should be set by now.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.getCurrentProfile();
  console.log("Profile Type is: " + this.state.profileType);
}
```

And still, logging this, gives me `undefined`.

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure `nextProps.profile` is set on the initial render?

Comment: Nothing obvious. :/ Make sure `getCurrentProfile` and `render` aren't messing with the state at all. (An accidental `this.state.profileType = undefined` in either place would cause this.)